# Abrir un modal desde otra pagina

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Que tal, quisiera saber como puedo hacer para poder abrir un `modal` desde otra pagina, ya que quiero mandarlo a llamar desde la barra de navegacion, para poder mostrarlo desde x pagina

Este es mi `modal`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="padding: 35px 50px;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp Nuevo Usuario</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 40px 50px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_who" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Who" AutoComplete="off" required></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span1"><i class="fa fa-universal-access" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <asp:TextBox required ID="Txt_pay" onkeypress='validate(event)' runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Payroll Number" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span2"><i class="fa fa-child" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <asp:TextBox required ID="Txt_name" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span3"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <asp:TextBox required ID="Txt_ou" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="OU" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span4"><i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <asp:TextBox required ID="Txt_pool" onkeypress='validate(event)' runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Pool" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span5"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <asp:TextBox required ID="Txt_team" onkeypress='validate(event)' runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Team" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span6"><i class="fa fa-gavel" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <asp:TextBox required ID="Txt_rol" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Rol" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span7"><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <asp:TextBox type="password" required ID="Txt_pass" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" Text="Guardar" OnClick="Btn_submitData" />
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

y este es el de mi barra de navegacion:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: con @Html.ActionLink("Titulo", "Action", "Controller"), titulo es el texto que quieras action  es el nombre del action en tu controller y controller es el nombre del controller

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes, lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:
1ero - En tu barra de navegación debes agregar un botón de la siguiente forma:

```
<li><a href="#" class="page-scroll" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modal</a></li>
```

2do - Para llamar el modal en la sección de scripts del su Layout agregar lo siguiente:

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            });
     });
</script>
```